# Output from /etc/passwd Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, output

please help write this script. All logins starting with "be" and ending with "n" with GID = 500 should be output from the / etc / passwd file (Information should be presented in the form of a table). You need to do this through awk. Please help

Comment: It's unclear where you're stuck at, unclear what you've tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You need to show in your question what you have tried, how it has failed and have a more specific question then, "please write the script" for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to accomplish that :

```
awk -F':'  'BEGIN{ OFS="\t" } { $1=$1; if ( $1 ~ /^be.*n$/ && $4 == 500  ){ print $0 }}' /etc/passwd
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: U forgot END {} at the end :)